# Cloudformation - define default value in a map

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I want to access the value `MyVar`with:

```
 '!FindInMap [!Ref Stage, !Ref AWS::Region, MyVar]'
```

```
Mappings:
  stage1:
    us-west-2:
      MyVar: 15
  stage2:
    us-west-2:
      MyVar: 15
  stage3:
    eu-west-1:
      MyVar: 20
    us-east-1:
      MyVar: 30
```

I have to define a Stage variable (username-stage1) which is not present in the Mappings. Is there a way I can define a default value? I would like to have a feature where,

> If matching key1, key2 not found, return MyVar as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no such functionality in CloudFormation for `Mappings`. You can have default values for `Parameters`, if that would be of any help.